# How to figure out whether PCA can be performed on a data set or not?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, algorithms

I do have idea on the way PCA works but I do not know how to figure out whether a high dimensional data set is suited for PCA compression. I googled for some algorithms but could find any. Are there some algorithms that help us to decide whether PCA can be performed in a data set or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "PCA can be performed"? PCA is a numerical algorithm, so it can always be performed .... Consider asking your real question on Cross Validated instead.

Comment: How can you decide whether a high dimensional data set is suited for PCA compression ?

Comment: Consider asking that question on Cross Validated instead, you will get better answers there!